# Intellij generate java code with JAXB returns xsd file

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I'm new to java and i'm facing a problem

I'm trying to generate java code based on xsd files (this worked fine with my xsd files and WSCF.blue in my .net project).
In Intellij I'm using "Generate java code from xml schema using jaxb"

Here are the settings that I use:

[image]

When I look in my QueryEngine.Contracts folder, it has just copied the xsd file:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is ?

Comment: I found out why. In one of my xsd files, there are some errors, that the commandprompt says the following about: "Cannot resolve the name 'tns:LandsejerlavNavn' to a(n) 'element declaration' compontent. I have three of those errors. If i remove the three lines that gives this error, it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out why. In one of my xsd files, there are some errors, that the commandprompt says the following about: "Cannot resolve the name 'tns:LandsejerlavNavn' to a(n) 'element declaration' compontent.

I have three of those errors. If i remove the three lines that gives this error, it works

I wonder why I get that error, when WSCF.blue in my .net project can create .cs files just fine.

Comment: I was able to bypass the error in the command promp by setting the -nv tag to the xjc command. So now i'm able to generate the java files i need.

Comment: i am facing the same problem: how did u set the -nv tag to the xjc command in intelliJ?

Comment: @pebbles I didn't. I ended up creating a c# application, that would transform all my xsd files with JAXB through CMD

Comment: wow, that sounds weird, u have have been really frustrated :D. ty anyway

Comment: I never got intellij to work with generating xsd files. And we had more than a 1000 xsd files from an old solution that had to be used to generate java files.
So instead of wasting time trying to figure out how to get intellij how to do it, it was easier to create a c# application that would loop through all the directories and create a command line window and execute:
/C xjc -d {0} {1} -nv

Comment: Make sure to validate the XSD on Intellij. Also scan/read through the XSD to see that there are no errors. This was the process I followed when IntelliJ didn't create the Java Objects.